# MD5, unicode и multibyte

Tags: c++, unicode, md5, криптография

Вопрос простой, но я в нем не компетентен, хотелось бы выслушать "опытных".

Есть простой класс, который в конструкторе принимает любую строку и с помощью алгоритма "MD5" преобразовывает в то, что должен преобразовать, так вот я решил скомпилировать проект в "UNICODE" и сравнить результаты алгоритмов в "MULTIBYTE" и "UNICODE" кодировках, переделал класс под юникод (так как он был сделан под мультибайтовую кодировку) и на выходе получил разные результаты алгоритмов(юникод и мультибайт), я знаю что под символ юникода выделяется 2 байта, соответственно код символа другой, так вот хотелось бы узнать, MD5 так и должен давать другой результат выполнения алгоритма в юникоде или его не корректно использовать в юникоде вообще?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MD5 - алгоритм хеширования сообщения. Но никто не говорит о том, что сообщение обязательно должно быть текстовым. MD5 (как и остальные подобные алгоритмы) воспринимает поток данных (биты, байты). Поэтому результат, полученный Вами, вполне закономерен.

> P.S:Искать другие алгоритмы, которые будут работать с различными
>   кодировками строк, выдавая аналогичный результат для одинаковых строк
>   в разных кодировках, не имеет смысла. Проще приводить все к одной
>   кодировке.

Comment: вопрос немного не по теме - но все же - можешь посоветовать библиотеку для работы с алгоритмами?

Comment: Раньше пользовался [beecrypt](http://beecrypt.sourceforge.net/), но в последнее время, когда возникает необходимость в том или ином алгоритме, то нахожу отдельно нужные 1-2 исходных файла в сети и включаю их в проект. Со временем все нужные основные алгоритмы уже есть.

Comment: я думал один так делаю-)

Answer (score 5):

md5 работает с байтами. Они ничего не знает о символах и кодировках. Поэтому, это абсолютно ожидаемо, что для различных кодировок один и тот же текст будет давать различные результаты. Если же нужно, что бы результат был один и тот же, можно в программе условиться, что md5 считается только юникоде или другой заданной кодировке. И перед расчетом md5, строку приводить к нужной кодировке.

Comment: Ну не совсем с байтами, скорее с битами, хотя большинство реализаций конечно байтами принимает.

Comment: Если присмотрется к описанию, то да, там биты везде написаны, но на всех этапах их кол-во кратно 8.  А в большинстве реализаций байт как раз из 8 бит и состоит.

Comment: Хотел сказать, что md5 для одного единичного бита и байта 0x01 будет разный.